# Magento 2 - Sample module displays blank page

Tags: magento2, module, layout, magento-2.0

I'm using Magento 2 version beta-1.0.0 and trying to create a simple new custom module. The custom module works but is showing a blank page on body content.

The module done in below way.

Folder Structure: Hello

```
-app
    -code
        -Magento
            -Hello
                -Block
                    --Hello.php
                -Controller
                    -Index
                        --Index.php
                -etc
                    --module.xml
                    -frontend
                        --routes.xml
                -view
                    -frontend
                        -layout
                            --hello_index_index.xml
                        -templates
                            --hello.phtml
```

Files are as follow.

(1) app/code/Magento/Hello/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magento_Hello" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

(2) app/code/Magento/Hello/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="hello" frontName="hello">
            <module name="Magento_Hello"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

(3) app/code/Magento/Hello/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

(4) app/code/Magento/Hello/Block/Hello.php

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Hello\Block;

class Hello extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

(5) app/code/Magento/Hello/view/frontend/layout/hello_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Hello to Magento 2.0</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Hello\Block\Hello" name="hello" template="hello.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

(6) app/code/Magento/Hello/view/frontend/templates/hello.phtml

```
<?php echo "This is simple hello module on Magento 2.0"; ?>
```

Once module created I've updated Magento setup as well.

> cd [magento2_root_folder_path] 
>  php bin/magento setup:upgrade

And if I go to

> http://localhost/magento2/hello/index/index it shows blank under "body" tag. I'm sure module is loading properly since "head" tag appears with  the Title.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong at a glance. Blank after a point suggests PHP error. Have you checked your server's PHP error logs? Or tried enabling error displaying?

Comment: @Ryan: Yes, I've checked PHP error logs and nothing is appeared there. Enabled error displaying by adding error_reporting(E_ALL) & 
ini_set('display_errors', '1') on index.php. But didn't appear any errors. Module seems working since <title> tag appears correctly, but nothing under <body> tag.

Comment: Is that the correct folder structure because it seems you are missing a level between Magento and your module structure. Probably just a typo but should be contained in 'Hello'.

Comment: @Smartie: My bad. yes, it was a typo error. I've updated the question.

Comment: try adding this `layout="2columns-left"` on the `page` node in the `hello_index_index.xml` file

Comment: @Marius: Great. It worked :). I should have thought that. Thanks. Please add this as an answer so I'll up-vote it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to specify the layout for the page.
So add this `layout="2columns-left"` on the `<page>` node in `hello_index_index.xml`.
You can also use `1column`, `2columns-right`, `3columns` or `empty`.

Comment: Is there error logging for this Marius? If not I may open an issue on git.

Comment: I have no idea.